# What does thread-safe and unsafe functions and cancellation point mean?

Tags: c, pthreads

The pthreads man page mentioned a list of thread safe and unsafe functions, and I didn't understand the term "cancellation point" relating these functions.

What exactly are they?

Comment: There is plenty of information on SO and other sites about the meaning of "thread safe" and "cancellation point". You should google those terms.

Comment: Consider reading the POSIX section on [Threads](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_09) which includes 'thread safety' and 'cancellation points' as topics.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374707/what-exactly-is-a-cancellation-point

Comment: `In pthreads man page` - and the terms are explained in the same man page. Did you read it? Which part didn't you understand?